# Typechecking Hack code on VirtualBox via NFS shared folder

Tags: nfs, hhvm, hacklang

It seems prudent to first mention [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2311) and then [this aptly-named edit](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/3f8842fab4049041a36c8b808a2c38621a9c6bea#comments) which seems related and has made hh_server refuse to run on NFS file systems. I am not very familar with file systems and have never touched OCaml before, so in trying to accomplish the question title, I have tried editing what I know: `/etc/hh.conf` and `/etc/hhvm/{php, server}.ini`, adding `hhvm.[server.]enable_on_nfs = true` by pure guesswork. No dice.

As I understand it from the issue, the change stems from the `hh_server` daemon being unable to register changes to the files via inotify on NFS drives, which is totally understandable. However, my VirtualBox is purely a test server for me familiarizing myself with Hack (i.e. only running the typechecker), and I've successfully run hh_client on sshfs-mounted (osxfuse) drives before. Is there another problem I'm not aware of that makes this a bad idea? If not, how might I enable `hh_server --check` to run on my VBox NFS shared folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the lack of `inotify` support for NFS, so `hh_server` may respond with stale data.

If you accept the risk, you can add `enable_on_nfs = true` to `/etc/hh.conf`, which will enable `hh_server` to check folders on NFS.

Comment: Oh, HHVM caches the typechecker's errors as well? I always thought it rechecked the entire project, not just the files that had changed. 

Also, `enable_on_nfs = true` is the only setting in my project root and it seems to be being ignored.

Comment: HHVM gets its pre-runtime static typechecker errors by asking `hh_server`, so if `hh_server` is stale then its errors will be stale too. I would seriously recommend against running this off of NFS -- the error is there for a reason!

Comment: @JoshWatzman What part of `hh_server` goes stale? If I understand correctly, without `inotify` support, `hh_server` isn't informed to which files have changed, but how can/does it return the errors in every file by only checking the files that have changed anyways (presuming that's what the `inotify` updates are used for)? This logic was why my initial impression was that `hh_server` rechecks every file for every call to the typechecker.

Comment: On initial start up, `hh_server` does have to check every file, but from then on, it can incrementally update its state based on the `inotify` events. It does not need to recheck every file anytime anything changes, and definitely not every call to `hh_client`. For more details, I gave a tech talk about the typechecker a year or so ago, the second part delves into how this works some -- the details have changed in the intervening year but the gist is the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aN22-V-b8RM&feature=youtu.be&t=39m

Comment: @JoshWatzman Whoa, cool! One of the few times I'm happy to be wrong.

Comment: Is there a way NOT to use NFS with VirtualBox? I'm running into a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310109/hhvm-with-homestead-hhvm-refusing-nfs)

Comment: @concat I've figured out what actually needs to be done to get NFS to work. You need to set the option in `/etc/hh.conf`, not the project root. I've updated my answer to match.