# HHVM with Homestead - HHVM refusing NFS

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead, hhvm

I'm trying to set up [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) with VirtualBox and the HHVM option.
My host is Mac OS, and I'm not enabling the nfs option in Homestead.yaml.
However, as soon as I add a Hack file and run hh_client, hh_server dies because it refuses [to run on NFS](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/3f8842fab4049041a36c8b808a2c38621a9c6bea#comments)

I understand the rational of not supporting NFS but I'm wondering why is NFS actually involved here, and what could be done to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox shared folders are effectively a network folder, causing the same problems as NFS. [This answer, and my comments on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37066806/3395144), explain why `hh_server` (and thus Hack code) doesn't work on NFS -- the kernel doesn't provide the right inotify events to update its internal state.

Comment: Thanks. I assume there's no workaround then. `enable_on_nfs = true` in .hhconfig seems ignored as well.

Comment: While I'm surprised that option doesn't work, seriously the error is there for a reason; you're going to get random stale type errors if you ever modify the code running underneath HHVM or `hh_server` unless you properly restart both daemons.

Comment: Yes I think I'll do w/o it for now. Just thought like mentioning that option doesn't seem to work anyway.