# ide exit with exit code 206 while running hh_client

Tags: hhvm

I am trying to run hh_client locally using docker for mac(beta). After running 
hh_client start
hh_client

It responds with `hh_server died unexpectedly. Maybe you recently launched a different version of hh_server. Now exiting hh_client`

```
fe1a7a:/var/www/app# tail -f $(hh_client --monitor-logname) $(hh_client --logname)
==> /tmp/hh_server/zSvarzSwwwzSapp.monitor_log <==

[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Just started typechecker server with pid: 60.
[2016-05-31 21:01:15] About to spawn ide daemon. Logs will go to /tmp/hh_server/zSvarzSwwwzSapp.ide_log

[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Just started ide server with pid: 61.
[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Got request for typechecker. Prior request 0.0 seconds ago
[2016-05-31 21:01:17] ide exit with exit code 206

[2016-05-31 21:01:17] typechecker exit with exit code 1


==> /tmp/hh_server/zSvarzSwwwzSapp.log <==
[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Could not load config at /etc/hh.conf, using defaults
Failure("statfs failed")
```

I used to use vagrant/virtualbox without these issues.

```
hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.13.1 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.13.1-0-g4f382ad928a6e2a0607a8dcb251002aca77f11f6
Repo schema: 655b5912cb8136e9df6f9be972153e38ac446e0f
```

php.ini

```
; php options
;
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/php5
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; hhvm specific
;hhvm.jit_warmup_requests = 10

hhvm.server.port=9000
hhvm.server.type=fastcgi
hhvm.server.source_root=/var/www/app/public
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php

hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.level = Verbose
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.log.header = true
hhvm.log.use_sys_log = true
hhvm.log.injected_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.native_stack_trace = true
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 1
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false

hhvm.hack.lang.look_for_typechecker = false
hhvm.utf8 = true
```

The ide_log file returned the following. I'm not what this means though

```
Error, only read 0 bytes for preamble.
[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Marshal_tools.Reading_Preamble_Exception
Raised at file "utils/marshal_tools.ml", line 98, characters 10-36
Called from file "server/ideProcessPipe.ml", line 27, characters 4-8
[2016-05-31 21:01:15] Typechecker has died, exiting too.
```

Comment: Can you add the output of running `hh_server /var/www/app`? It looks like the server is dying and our client code isn't smart enough to print out the server logs :(

Comment: That said my guess is that you're running into the networked FS issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37066806/3395144